# Match File1 with File 2

Tags: text-processing, bioinformatics

I have two files, In File1 there are Gene Interactions (Gene Symbol) and the other File2 has the Gene Symbol and its corresponding Ensembl ID.

File1

```
GeneA GeneB
GeneA GeneD
GeneC GeneB
```

File2

```
GeneA    Ensembl1
GeneB    Ensembl2
GeneC    Ensembl3
```

Now I want a file which has the output like this
File3

```
GeneA Ensembl1 GeneB Ensembl2
GeneA Ensembl1 GeneD NA
GeneC Ensembl3 GeneB Ensembl2
```

If you notice there was no GeneD in File2 and so when no Ensembl ID was found for this gene, NA was entered against it.
Can anybody help me achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
perl -lane '
   @ARGV and $h{$F[0]}=$F[1],next;
   print join $", map { $_ , $h{$_} // "NA" } @F;
' File2 File1
```

---

### Results

```
GeneA Ensembl1 GeneB Ensembl2
GeneA Ensembl1 GeneD NA
GeneC Ensembl3 GeneB Ensembl2
```

---

### Working

- Supply File2 first, then File1 in the arguments list to Perl.
- Build up a hash `%h` whose keys are GeneA,GeneB,etc. => values are Ensembles from File2. Note while processing File2, the @ARGV has one element so @ARGV in scalar context returns a true.
- During the time of File1 read-in, @ARGV reduces to zero, so the first line is not evaluated. The 2nd line will print the fields after an appropriate mapping transform and joined together via spaces ($" defaults to space).

Answer (score 2):

***awk*** solution:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{ a[$1]=$2; next }
     { $1=$1 FS (($1 in a)? a[$1]:"NA"); $2=$2 FS (($2 in a)? a[$2]:"NA"); }1' File2 File1
```

The output:

```
GeneA Ensembl1 GeneB Ensembl2
GeneA Ensembl1 GeneD NA
GeneC Ensembl3 GeneB Ensembl2
```

Comment: @saamarrajput, you're welcome